# How can I configure the in-memory Camunda database to accept longer string process variables?

Tags: h2, camunda

```
[error]  org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Value too long for column "TEXT_ VARCHAR(4000)":
```

Camunda needs to be configured by some ALTER TABLE statements to allow for very long process variables of type String in the database.

How does one do this for the in-memory unit test database (where there is no admin tool to modify the schema as the database is transient)?

Or is there an option to have Strings stored as binary serializations just like Java objects (which apparently can be longer) instead of a text column?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your last question, try this:

```
RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();

VariableMap variables = Variables.createVariables();
variables.putValueTyped("var", Variables
          .objectValue(aLongStringValue)
              // tells the engine to use java serialization for persisting the value 
          .serializationDataFormat(SerializationDataFormats.JAVA)  
          .create());

// Start a process instance
ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("testProcess", variables);
```

Limitations of this approach are:

- You cannot use this variable in queries, for example `runtimeService.createVariableInstanceQuery().variableValueEquals("var", aLongStringValue).list()` would not find the variable
- Whenever you fetch the variable, you will have to use the API that returns deserialized values (e.g. `RuntimeService.getVariable("name") or RuntimeService.getVariableTyped("name", true)`) to get the actual value. This can be a problem if you rely on the feature that the engine can serve variables in their serialized format (which is for a regular `String` variable just the plain `String` value; for a Java-serialized `Object` value, it is a base64-encoded String of the byte representation).

Comment: `getVariable("key")` is still fine. With `getVariableTyped("key", false)`, you will no longer be able to retrieve the actual String value. My formulation is not exact, I'll update it.

Comment: Also, in the code to set this up, do I need to know the variable names (here `"var"`) in advance? Can this be set globally for all Strings?

Comment: I assume you rather mean the type of the variable value, right? Using only public API, you would need code that identifies a String value and the uses the code above to create an object value. To always serialize Strings via Java object serialization, you could also remove the StringValueSerializer from the engine configuration (see org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl#initSerialization). This can be done by creating a custom engine configuration class or probably from within a process engine plugin.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I'm seeing this error but not during creation (it saves correctly), rather when I start execution at `runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(ID)`? @thorben Is there any way I can show you my code?

Comment: If I remove the StringValueSerializer from the configuration, will the engine then store it in a data type that will not error out? I asked my similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367061) in SO too. Sorry for all the comments but I've been trying to resolve this for at least a week.

Answer (score 4):

I found a [thread about the subject](https://forums.activiti.org/content/increase-lenght-string-process-variables) and expanding on what was proposed there as a "hacky workaround", I could make my test cases pass by putting this code in the setup phase:

```
// allow longer texts:
// https://forums.activiti.org/content/increase-lenght-string-process-variables

val processEngineConfiguration = engine.getProcessEngineConfiguration()
val session = processEngineConfiguration
     .asInstanceOf[ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl]
     .getDbSqlSessionFactory().getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
val connection = session.getConnection()
val jdbcStatement = connection.createStatement()
jdbcStatement.execute("ALTER TABLE ACT_RU_VARIABLE ALTER TEXT_ CLOB");
jdbcStatement.execute("ALTER TABLE ACT_HI_VARINST ALTER TEXT_ CLOB");
jdbcStatement.execute("ALTER TABLE ACT_HI_DETAIL ALTER TEXT_ CLOB");
jdbcStatement.close();
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/o-nix/a036f5a83c4a5b3a98c7?ts=2 configuration bean with your code.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Camunda in a Spring Boot jar you can add a data.sql in
/src/main/resources with the update statements.

```
ALTER TABLE ACT_RU_VARIABLE ALTER TEXT_ CLOB;
ALTER TABLE ACT_HI_VARINST ALTER TEXT_ CLOB;
ALTER TABLE ACT_HI_DETAIL ALTER TEXT_ CLOB;
```